# Check if NSEntityDescription key exists

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5, nsentitydescription

I need to check if an `NSEntityDescription` key exists before trying to set the value. I have a dictionary of data from JSON and don't want to try setting keys that do not exist in my object.

```
Appointment *appointmentObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Appointments" inManagedObjectContext:[[DataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
for (id key in dict) {
    // Check if the key exists here before setting the value so we don't error out.
        [appointmentObject setValue:[dict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should not check for selectors. Imagine a key called `entity` or `managedObjectContext`. The NSManagedObject class definitely responds to those selectors, but the best thing that will happen if you try to assign something wrong to those is that your code crashes instantly. A little less luck and something like this destroys the complete core data file, and all the user data.

`NSEntityDescription` has a method named [`attributesByName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001173-BCIDDFGC) which returns a dictionary with your attribute names and corresponding `NSAttributeDescriptions`. So these keys are basically all the attributes you can use.

Something like this should work:

```
Appointment *appointmentObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Appointments" inManagedObjectContext:[[DataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext]];
NSArray *availableKeys = [[appointmentObject.entity attributesByName] allKeys];
for (id key in dict) {
    if ([availableKeys containsObject:key]) {
        // Check if the key exists here before setting the value so we don't error out.
        [appointmentObject setValue:[dict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
}
```

Comment: You make a very good point! Since I am relying on a JSON response to provide the keys, it is VERY possible for them to have keys that respond to normal selectors.

Answer (score 6):

Check this,

`BOOL hasFoo = [[myObject.entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"foo"] != nil;`

Comment: Great!  Very elegant way to check.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking that you want to check if the appointmentObject responds to a property. In that case:

```
if([appointmentObject respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)])...
```

The getter equivalent is propertyName.
The setter equivalent is setPropertyName.

Comment: is this the same as `respondsToSelector:@selector(key)`? If so I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: is the key a string or another type of object? I assumed it was a string.

Comment: all `@property` are `NSString` except for one which is `NSNumber`, however the error is when it encounters a key that is not in the `Appointment` class.

Comment: -1 because checking for selectors is not save for something like this. You could set the `managedObjectContext`, or the `entity` with this code. And because you just check for the getter you could even set the `description` of the class. At least the app would try to set them, and crash when it actually does.